# Truffle send to fallback function from different account

Tags: truffle, fallback-function, truffle-test

I'm testing a simple fallback function with Truffle, the fallback function is:

```
function () public payable {
    internalTransfer(this, msg.sender, 100000000);
    FundSuccess(msg.sender, msg.value);
}

function internalTransfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) 
  internal returns (bool) {
    // SafeMath.sub will throw if there is not enough balance.
    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    return true;
}
```

where .sub and .add are imported from SafeMath library, in the truffle test I have

```
trx = await token.send(power18(1), {from: accounts[1]});
console.log(trx);
var balance1 = await token.balanceOf.call(accounts[1]);
console.log(balance1);
```

what I found was, no matter what I specify in the from, balance is always assigned to account[0]. Checking the transaction in Ganache shows that the transaction was recorded as sent from account[0].

I know {from:...} works, I have used it in other places and never had a problem. This is the first time I used it on ".send". I am at a stage where I do not know how to proceed, tried googling but couldn't find good information, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `send` ignores the `tx_params`  (aka the `{from: val, ...}`) object.

Here's its [implementation](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/blob/develop/contract.js#L320).

You can use `sendTransaction` instead, which works as expected:

```
token.sendTransaction({from: accounts[1], value: 10**18})
```

IMO this was poorly documented, and the usage of `send` should conform to the standard that most other functions have set.

Comment: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/issues/101 looks like you opened the issue, thanks a lot, linking here for people with the same problem in the future